# Proper Way To Type Annotate a function which returns an array of PIL Images

Tags: python

I have a function that loads all images in a directory, `get_images()`. How do I properly type annotate the function to denote that it returns an array of images?

The following gives error:

```py
import os
from PIL import Image
from typing import List

def get_images(folder: str)->List[Image]:
    images = []
    for path in os.listdir(folder):
        if path.endswith(".jpg"):
            img_path = "/".join([folder, path])
            print(img_path)
            img = Image.open(img_path)
            images.append(img)
    return images
```

```
TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got <module 'PIL.Image' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packa.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `List[Image]` you are calling a list of modules `Image`, what you want is the type of object `Image.Image`
So it would be:

```
def get_images(folder: str)->List[Image.Image]:
```

Answer (score 2):

The return type from `Image.open` is `Image.Image`:

```
def get_images(folder: str) -> List[Image.Image]:
```